# I can not add navigation item to navigation bar

Tags: iphone

I add a Navigation Bar to an view, I noticed that there is no left side arrow(Navigation Item).
so I drag a Navigation Item from library to Navigation Bar, the green mark "+" displayed, but the Navigation Item was not added to the Navigation Bar actually.

Welcome any comment

Thanks
interdev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your navigation bar have a stack? Even without using it in a `UINavigationController`, you can maintain a stack of navigation controllers. I suspect that the "Back" button will only display if there's something behind your current view controller. So, try the [`-setItems:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationBar/setItems:animated:) method on your navigation bar and see if putting something behind the current view helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I do nor use UINavigationController, I construct the gui and controll by myself